# How can we solve the below scenario?

Tags: asp.net, web-farm, web-garden

We have one application which is hosted on 4 different server if support the one web server is down that time what will going to be happen for the user who is going to do transaction on that particular web server.

Can any one explain me the scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

I think if the user already triggers the transaction , the transaction should rollback and the user should see something fail. If the user haven't, the user should be redirect to another server which depends on which type LB you use and how the user's session shares between servers.